# How can I convert existing ethereum token to new coin

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, tokens

How can I convert a Token e.g. **TOT**(built on ethereum) to Coin **TOT** e.g. with same name and same value in another public blockchain?

Or is there any way to convert token value to new coin using new blockchain network?

Comment: I want to create a new coin like TOT in a new  blockchain where TOT was token previously in Ethereum blockchain. btw everything here is only for learning purpose and imaginary thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly, you want to have your own blockchain based on your token.

https://poa.net can help you with that by using bridge technology:

Live production  version: https://bridge.poa.net
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OstGQQHgCt4

1. Choose which consensus mechanism you want for your blockchain(POA, POW, etc)
2. If you want a POA-like chain, feel free to reuse our governance, Voting Dapps, Ceremony, deployment tools and bunch of other free and open sourced software that we have built for you at POA.network.
   Our deployed versions:
   https://voting.poa.network ( have metamask pointed to https://core.poa.network RPC endpoint)
   https://ceremony.poa.network
3. When you have deployed your own network, you can setup a bridge which will allow your users to convert their ERC20 tokens to your native coin.

No need to suicide your contract or something, and you can keep your ERC20 listed if it was listed on exchanges.

Comment: Yeah !!!  You understood what I mean :). Btw I am checking links

Comment: @sharif.io you  can even check live, deployed, production version of the bridge:
https://bridge.poa.net. You can send POA native coin across chains ( from POA.network to Ethereum mainnet as ERC20) back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you included a suicide function to destroy your old smart contract such that no new tokens are created. Basically, the easiest way to do this is to first freeze the assets of the old token.

If the chain you're creating is EVM-like, you can simply create a new genesis block with coin values assigned to each token holder.

If you're working with a brand new blockchain interface, you're going to need to communicate directly with your token holders somehow in order to give them the private key holding their coins on the new chain. Instruct them to then move the coins into an address made by a private key that you dont own.

Tezos did this by collecting emails of all token purchasers. I am hoping you did not run an ICO and are now only figuring how to launch your chain.